# How to turn a random 3 digit input (numbers) to 3 seperate integers in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

So as the title says, I need to take a user input (e.g. 456) and seperate those numbers so I end up with 4, 5 and 6. The input won't ever be more than 3 digits, however it could be any 3 digits, and it is always going to be numbers. I am very new to Python and coding in general, so my code is sloppy, messy and probably (very) wrong.
The code I have currently is as follows:

```
`

     myint=input
     mystr=str(myint) 
     print(mystr) 
     mystr[0] 
     mystr[1] 
     mystr[2] 
     int(mystr[0]) 
     int(mystr[1]) 
     int(mystr[2]) 
     globals() mystr[0] = a mystr[1] = b mystr[2] = c
```

`

This all takes place within my first function

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, you can't just describe your (homework?) problem and expect us to give you code. Rather, try solving it yourself and ask about any issues you're having (we'll be happy to help out). Regarding your actual question, how are you getting the input? Is it as a string (with e.g. `raw_input`) or are you writing a function and the single integer is a parameter? Do you need to deal with integers less than 100 (which might not have a leading `0`)?

Comment: Sorry I should have said, I was originally trying something along the lines of
`myint=input
        mystr=str(myint)
        print(mystr)
        mystr[0]
        mystr[1]
        mystr[2]
        int(mystr[0])
        int(mystr[1])
        int(mystr[2])
        globals()
        mystr[0] = a
        mystr[1] = b
        mystr[2] = c`

I'm really new to Python and have very little experience with coding at all, and it's this bit that has me stumped.

Comment: Please edit the code into the question, where you can format it better (with proper indentation especially, since that's important in Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = raw_input("Please enter a number")
y = [int(x[0]), int(x[1]), int(x[2])]
```

You can access the different digits using `y[0]`, `y[1]` and `y[2]`

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

create a string from the input like: str(number)
and then iterate through

```
number = 456
number = str(number)
for i in range(len(number)):
    print(number[i])
```

you should take a look at "strings" "lists" and "arrays" in python and how to handle them. It's pretty basic stuff

Answer (score 0):

You should always remember that a string is an array of chars. That is how Python handles them and you can always call a position of the array.

Answer (score 0):

In order to separate an integer into separate digits, you can use this one-liner:

```
digits = [int(i) for i in str(original_number)]
```

This way is more flexible than the accepted answer above, which hard-codes the indexes. Not that it's wrong, but just not as flexible in the case that you have a much larger amount of numbers. At some point, you'll want to do it more programmatically. Hope this helps too!